# Уникальные поля для БД MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица для комментариев пользователя, создаю так, как показано ниже. Нужно, чтобы id комментария и id человека который отправил комментарий не повторялись, собственно сделал их уникальными, но id комментариев всё равно назначаются по порядку (1, 2, 3, 4... n) игнорируя уникальность для пользователя, в чем проблема?

```
CREATE TABLE comments(
    id_comment MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_user INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_send_user integer NOT NULL,
    author CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    date CHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    message TEXT NOT NULL,
    img CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_user,id_comment)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Вроде решил проблему, пока всё работает, заменил `PRIMARY KEY` (`id_user,id_comment`) на `PRIMARY KEY` (`id_send_user,id_comment`).

Comment: UNIQUE INDEX whatever (id_comment, id_user)?

Comment: неа, "Индексы PRIMARY и whatever равнозначны и один из них может быть удалён."

Answer (score 1):

В структуре таблицы такой порядок автоназначения идентификатором задать невозможно. Можно либо с помощью триггера, либо изменить запрос добавления новой записи:

```
SET @id_user = 1;
SELECT MAX(id_comment) FROM comments WHERE id_user = @id_user INTO @id_last;
INSERT INTO comments VALUE (IFNULL@id_last, 0) + 1, @id_user, .......);
```

1. Получаем `@id_last` - максимальное значения `id_comment` для заданного `@id_user`.
2. Вставляем запись.

Код триггера должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_comments_bi
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON comments
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE _id_last INT(11) DEFAULT NULL;
    IF ISNULL(NEW.id_comment) THEN
        SELECT MAX(id_comment) FROM comments WHERE id_user = NEW.id_user
        INTO _id_last;    
        SET NEW.id_comment = IFNULL(_id_last, 0) + 1;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

AUTO_INCREMENT убери у id_comment

Comment: и как он будет назначить id? убрал A_I, теперь все id сообщений равны нулю и одно сообщение заменяет в базе другое

Comment: UNIQUE INDEX, и можешь AUTO_INCREMENT поле добавить id